# Rock, Paper, Scissors game with two inputs

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I am a newby and I am learning how to program in python on my own. I am trying to run a program of rock, paper, scissors game where I input player1 and player2 choice and tells me who wins. But for whatever reason the while loop does not stop running. I would appreciate any help! Thanks a lot for everything! This is the code that I wrote so far:

```
while player1 == input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?"):
#set player to True
    player2 = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")
    if player1 == player2:
        print("Tie!")
    elif player1 == "Rock":
        if player2 == "Paper":
            print("You lose!", player2, "covers", player1)
        else:
            print("You win!", player1, "smashes", player2)
    elif player1 == "Paper":
        if player2 == "Scissors":
            print("You lose!", player2, "cut", player1)
        else:
            print("You win!", player1, "covers", player2)
    elif player1 == "Scissors":
        if player2 == "Rock":
            print("You lose...", player2, "smashes", player1)
        else:
            print("You win!", player1, "cut", player2)
    else:
        print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? To stop the loop after each match? Then you don't even need a loop. It's not very clear from the question.

Your code won't even enter the loop because you're not assigning nothing to player1.
You could wrap everything inside something like this

```
while True:
    player1 = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")
    player2 = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors?")
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop does not end unless you change the variable `player1` . You may also introduce `break` .